# transform json content to object

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework

```
getSpecificData(par) {
return this.afd.list('products/products', ref => ref.orderByChild('par').equalTo(par)).valueChanges();
}
```

In my components, i have this:

```
export class Product {
  name: string;
  price: string;
  quantity: string;
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    let aux =this.readData();
    console.log('Products', aux);
}
readData() {
    return this.firebaseService.getSpecificData(this.par).subscribe(
        items => {
            this.data = items,
            console.log('Data from Firebase ', this.data)
        }
    );
}
```

The "console.log('Data from Firebase ', this.data)" is printing data right, but "console.log('Products', aux);" is getting me undefined.

What i am doing wrong?

My aim is to iterate the array of data and transform each item into an object of type product.

Regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Your `readData` method doesn't return the actual records. Everything happens asynchronously, which is why it works within the `subscribe` handler (that bit only gets called when the asynchronous task has completed.

Quick timeline example:

1. `ionViewDidLoad()`
2. `let aux = this.readData();`
3. `readData()`
4. `return this.firebaseService.getSpecificData(this.par).subscribe(`
5. `);`
6. `console.log('Products', aux);` (TOO SOON!!!)
7. (call to firebase getSpecificData completes)
8. `items => {`
9. `this.data = items,` This is the point where `this.data` receives the items
10. `console.log('Data from Firebase ', this.data)`
11. `}`

Comment: Thank you. I understood your explanation very well. But, this way, how can i  transform the items into objects? It has to be asynchronous too? How to achieve it?

Comment: Yes, you have to work with the asynchronous action, effectively you need to trigger the use of the data inside your `subscribe` handler - you could call a method, or raise an event, or use the data in there.

Comment: Ok. So if i use the data inside my subscribe it should be ok, right? Like this 
// readData() {
    return this.firebaseService.getSpecificData(this.par).subscribe(
        items => {
            this.data = items,
            this.Products.push(new Product(element[0], element[1], element[3])),
            console.log('Data from Firebase ', this.data)
        }
    );
}//

But it didn't work :(

Comment: @ccorreia where did the `element` array come from... did you mean to use `this.data.element[0]` or similar? I assume the `console.log` bit works?

Comment: Fenton, You led me to the solution. I discovered, a bit, how the asynchronous call works. I published the solution. If you have any advice to improve, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The explanation from Fenton is correctly.

I figure out the solution. Don't know yet if is the best solution, but it is working fine.

In my provider, i have the following code:

```
    export class Product {
    name: string;
    price: string;
    quantity: string;
    constructor(name: string, price: string, quantity: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}


    getSpecificData(par) {
    return this.afd.list('products/products', ref => ref.orderByChild('par').equalTo(par)).valueChanges().map(items => {
        let results = items.map(item => {
            return new Product(
                item.name,
                item.price,
                item.quantity
            );
        })
        return results;
    });
}
```

And im my component a have this:

```
readData() {
    this.firebaseService.getSpecificData(this.stock).map(
        data => {
            this.products = data;
        }
    ).subscribe();
}
```

It is working fine. I am reading the result in my html file.

```
<ion-col *ngFor=" let product of products" >
        {{product.name}}
</ion-col>
```